# How to make wrapped items in flexbox horizontally align to the right side?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have two divs that are inside a flexbox.  When there is enough space horizontally for them to fit on the same line, they look like this:

[image: Two divs on the same horizontal plane]
When I use the css property `flex-wrap: wrap`, the two divs will appear on different lines while floating left:

[image]

I want the green one to align to the right side but exist on a separate line as the blue one when the wrapping occurs in flexbox.  It would look like this:

[image]

How do I do this with flexbox?

Here is the code:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blue {
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `justify-content` from the parent, and use `margin` on one of the children instead to separate them, then use `align-self: flex-end` on `.green` to align it to the bottom.

```css
.flexbox{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blue{
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:300px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.green{
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:300px;
  background-color:green;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

The only thing you need to do is add `margin-left: auto` to `.green`.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blue {
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  margin-left: auto; /* NEW */
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Here's an explanation of how this works:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your code, I added the `flex-direction:column;` instead of wrap, then defined `align-self` for each flex item

```css
.flexbox{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.blue{
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:300px;
  background-color:blue;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.green{
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:300px;
  background-color:green;
  align-self:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```